# How to use forceRefresh: true in msal-angular config?

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

Tried using MSAL Angular. Wanted to skip cache which store access token at client side.
Skip cache option is available in msal. [Ref](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-core#forcerefresh-to-skip-cache)

Library used
[msal-angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular) `@azure/msal-angular@1.x.x`

Config pass inside `MsalModule.forRoot({})` not accepting `forceRefresh`

What is the best way to `skipCache` i.e to not store access token on client and use `forceRefresh` in config?

Answer (score 1):

You should execute `acquireTokenSilent` with AuthenticationParameters - forceRefresh as `true`. According to the docs https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular#login-and-acquiretoken-apis

And also:

> This should not be used by default, because of the performance impact
> on your application. Relying on the cache will give your users a
> better experience, and skipping it should only be used in scenarios
> where you know the current cached data does not have up to date
> information. Example: Admin tool to add roles to a user that needs to
> get a new token with updates roles.

You can look around that method code on Github, if you need more information:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/src/UserAgentApplication.ts#L705